# Accessing static properties in form class - C#

Tags: c#

I am attempting an exercise to learn c# but stuck at one point. need help with understanding this logic.

I have my logic in this class:

```
class Class1
{
        private readonly string EmployeeName;
        private readonly decimal HoursWorked, PayRate, NetPay;

        public int TotalPaySlips { get; private set; }
        public decimal TotalGrossPay { get; private set; }
        public decimal TotalNetPay { get; private set; }

        public Class1(string employeeName, decimal hoursWorked, decimal payRate)
        {
            EmployeeName = employeeName;
            HoursWorked = hoursWorked;
            PayRate = payRate;
            NetPay = CalculateNetPay();
        }

        private decimal CalculateNetPay()
        {
            decimal grossPay = HoursWorked * PayRate;
            decimal federalTax = grossPay * 0.1075m;
            decimal stateTax = grossPay * 0.0463m;
            decimal socialSecTax = grossPay * 0.062m;
            decimal medicareTax = grossPay * 0.0145m;

            decimal netPay = grossPay - federalTax - stateTax - socialSecTax - medicareTax;
            TotalGrossPay+= grossPay;
            TotalNetPay += netPay;
            TotalPaySlips++;

            return netPay;
        }
}
```

On my form class there are two buttons:

One button is to display Total Net Pay on the label and another button to display Total PaySlips and Total Gross Pay.

For the Total Net Pay, I am able to display it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 aObj = new Class1(textBox1.Text, numericUpDown1.Value, numericUpDown2.Value);

    label1.Text = aObj.TotalNetPay.ToString();
}
```

But I am stuck on the second part. I have two labels for the other two static properties (Total Gross Pay, and Total no Of Slips) but I don't know how to use these properties in Form class.

If i use

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 aObj = new Class1(textBox1.Text, numericUpDown1.Value, numericUpDown2.Value);
    label2.Text = aObj.TotalPaySlips.ToString();
    label3.Text = aObj.TotalGrossPay.ToString();
}
```

, its not giving me the correct answer.

Can someone help me.

Comment: It seems like you are missing the `static` keyword on your properties to *actually* make them static. `public static decimal TotalGrossPay { get; private set; }`. Also to access a static property you need to access it from the type itself as it is shared between all instances.
(e.g.`label2.Text = Class1.TotalPaySlips.ToString();`)

Comment: Are you aware that after you add a control to a form, you're allowed to rename it to something other than the suggested "textbox27", "label46" etc? It's very hard to debug code that is a constant lookup exercise of "what's the first name textbox? 38 or 22?" and even harder for us on the internet who cannot see your form. Do everyone (including yourself) a favor and name your things sensibly..

Comment: What does *its not giving me the correct answer* actually mean? That's like saying to your mechanic "my car is making a noise!"

Comment: Please provide some sample input, the expected output and the actual output. Did you try debugging to see if the calculation was right?

Comment: You mention "static properties", but your code doesn't have any. So a new instance of Class1 will reset all fields and properties (TotalPaySlips will always be 1 after that `TotalPaySlips++`)

Comment: @RobinB I'd rather suggest making the `Class1` instance a class field in the Form instead of creating new instances on every button click, than making its properties static, though.

Comment: @Fildor I was trying to stay as unintrusive to his structure as possible to try to not deviate from his tutorial instructions. But generally, I agree that your suggestion would be the better way to go.

Comment: Yes, you are right @RobinB It's probably about learning `static`... some exercises are just weird ... Maybe it would help to know the requirements to come up with a helpful answer.